# What is the best way to iterate an nested object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I would like to ask which one is better, if neither of two is a good approach then what is the best approach in iterating nested models.

Approach # 1.

```
@categories = Category.all

@categories.each do |category|
   category.sub_categories.each do |sub_category|
     puts sub_category.name
   end
end
```

let's say I have 100 categories each containing 100 sub categories, therefore this appraoch will generate 100x100 queries

Approach #2.

```
@categories = Category.all
@sub_categories = SubCategory.all

@categories.each do |category|
    @sub_categories.each do |sub_category|
        if category.id == sub_category.category_id
          puts sub_category.name
        end
    end
end
```

Will have only 2 queries but will iterate the "@sub_categories" 100 times.

And I am wondering which one is better?

Comment: This would be easy enough to test both ways to determine which is better.  Even with eager loading, I'm not sure @CarlosDrew is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first is definitely better, especially since you can make use of [Rails' eager loading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) to reduce queries.

Here is what I'd do:

```
#controller  
@categories = Category.includes(:sub_categories)

#view, haml-style  
%ul
  - @categories.each do |category|
    %li
      %h2= category.name
      %ul
        - category.sub_category.each do |sub_category|
          %li= sub_category.name
```

Why is this better?

1. Reduce queries with Rails eager loading: the controller line above will run at most 2 queries
2. Simpler, clearer code
3. You're avoiding complicated, unnecessary code in the view/output for checking the match of `category.id == sub_category.category_id`.

**Further Notes on the 2nd Example**

Let's say you have 10 Categories with 10 Subcategories each for 100 total. The first example will do 10 iterations on `@category` with 10 iterations each on `includes(:sub_categories)`, for (and this is fuzzy math) 110 "array iterations" total.

The second example will do 10 iterations on `@category` with 100 iterations each on `@sub_categories`, for (fuzzy math again) 1010 "array iterations" total. This is definitely worse.

Answer (score 1):

Approach #2 is your better option.  Here's why...

As you've pointed out, approach #1 will query the database 100 times (actually 101, including the first query), where approach #2 only queries it twice.  Ruby is pretty efficient at processing through arrays, so the performance hit for iterating through an array (especially with only 100 records) is minimal.  Whereas database queries, even though rails is pretty good at caching results, are still very expensive to process.

Comment: Rails' eager loading is designed to avoid these N+1 query problems on associations.

Comment: Agreed, but I still think it's going to be faster to iterate the array, but I could be wrong.  Simple tests could easily solve this.

Comment: I humbly disagree, @Donovan. Putting aside issues of performance, overly complex code is almost always an indication of a design/approach problem. That id match test is an example of overly complex code. Overly complex code leads to low testability and low coder happiness.

Comment: Additionally, let's say you're not asking for `Category.all` but `Category.where(some_attr: 'foo')` --- then, loading `Subcategory.all` is especially bad because not all those Subcategory will actually be used with a subset of Category.